# Conversion tracking IGO_purchases

Tags: marketing-cloud, conversion

Morning :-)

- the checkbox "track conversion link" has been checked in email studio to track the conversion link.
- I sent the email, clicked the link and checked out the order: the confirmation order page contains the tracking code for conversion (see code below)
- The catalogue contains the ordered product
- Back in marketing cloud, the data extension **IGO_purchases** is well populated with my conversion stored as follows:

(dummy values)

sku = 123456

price = 29.00

orderID = 98765

timestamp = Feb 15 2021 6:05AM

job_ID = null

list_id = null

landing url = null

subscriber id = null

**Issue** The job ID is null. I would need this field to map which email was the source of this conversion. Purpose is to track generated purchases per email campaigns / journeys. Do you know how can I track this?

thank you in advance

the following code has been inserted to the confirmation order page (xxxxxxx to be replaced by the orgID. The order number and item data are populated dynamically, here is just an example):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//xxxxxxx.collect.igodigital.com/collect.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  _etmc.push(["setOrgId", "xxxxxxx"]);
  _etmc.push(["trackConversion", { "cart": [
     
       {"item" : '123456', "quantity":  '1', "price" : '29,00', "unique_id" : '123456' }

     
  ],
      "order_number": "98765"}]);
</script> ´´´
```

Comment: I believe this data is pi_sessions, have you looked at that DE

Comment: @eazyE PI_SESSIONS is empty...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1/ at the landing page save the j value (jobID) into a cookie.

2/ at the conversion page, pass the optional parameter JobID, the same way the order ID is passed in the case above. To do so, read the cookie j.

3/ the data extension PI_SESSIONS will store the JobID while IGO_purchase will store the order ID

4/ Query IGO_purchase and join PI_sessions on the user_id and session_id to get the conversion data.

The conversion data are (order ID, Job ID).

- the order ID allows you to retrieve all order details and customer details
- the job id allows you to know which email is the origin of the conversion